# Ng-model not correctly binding data to variable

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a variable that I have binded to a `select` input using `ng-model`. However, it looks like the variable is not being updated with the correct data and is still having the value it was assigned during initialization.

I have something almost exactly the same (dealing with different data) elsewhere in the `html`, and it works perfectly.

Here's where I set the default values:

```
var setDefaultProps = function () {
    $scope.SelectedEnv = [];
    $scope.SelectedWorkFlows = [];
    ...
}
```

This function is called right after it's declaration.

Here's the `html` for the portion that actually works:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-3 form-control-label">  WorkFlow</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="SelectedWorkFlows" ng-change="GetEnvironments()">
            <option ng-repeat="wf in lstWorkflowModel" ng-value="{{wf}}">{{wf.label}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I do a `console.log` on the `SelectedWorkFlows` variable in any function (`GetEnvironments` or something invoked later), I get the output desired (an object)

Here's the `html` for the portion that doesn't work:

```
<div ng-if="!IsSmoke" class="form-group row">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-3 form-control-label">  Environment</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <select id ="environmentSelect" class="form-control" ng-model="SelectedEnv" ng-change="GetUsers()">
            <option ng-repeat="env in lstOfPrefillmodel" ng-value="{{env}}">{{env.label}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Within the `GetUsers` function, once I do a `console.log` for `SelectedWorkflows`, I get the previous output. However, when I do a `console.log` for `SelectedEnv`, the value stays the same no matter what I select on my page (the initial value of an empty array).

It looks like I've initialized my variable, set everything else up correctly, and have two effectively identical sets of code that function differently. What should I be looking for to debug this correctly?

**EDIT**

(ere's a plunker that describes my situation [https://plnkr.co/edit/04vOmQKfyE564Nqi?preview>](https://plnkr.co/edit/04vOmQKfyE564Nqi?preview%3E).

I created this using exactly the structure of my current code, but for some reason it works here. I'm still observing the issues of my variable not changing value as described initially in my original code

Comment: Could you turn your code into a [mre] so we can see it in action?

Comment: Don't yout think SelectedEnv should be a string instead of array? and why are initializing the value inside a function and from where does this function gets invoked. As @RubenHelsloot mentioned please share a plunker or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I worked out a workaround (I doubt this is an actual solution to the problem, but hey).

I simply initialized the variable as an object. For example:

```
$scope.SelectedEnv = {}
```

Then, I binded the input to a field within the variable:

```
ng-model=SelectedEnv.data
```

Afterwards, all the data seems to be correctly binded.